# Getting PHP error "Fatal error: require_once() Failed opening required <file>"

Tags: php

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'includes/header.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\static\index.php on line 1

This is the document

```
<?php require_once('includes/header.php') ?>
    <title>Blog | Home </title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- container - wraps whole page -->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- navbar -->
        <?php include('includes/navbar.php') ?>

        <!-- Page content -->
        <div class="content">
            <h2 class="content-title">Recent Articles</h2>
            <hr>
            <!-- more content still to come here ... -->
        </div>
        <!-- // Page content -->

        <!-- footer -->
        <?php include('includes/footer.php') ?>
```

Comment: Does the file `C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\static\includes\header.php` exist?

Comment: yes it does exist

Comment: Tr listing the directory your pointing to i bet its not there.

Comment: how do i list all the directory and add them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for you header

```
<?php  $docroot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
require_once("$docroot/blog/static/includes/header.php");  ?>
```